# Unused Italian student visa

Tags: italy, pakistani-citizens, student-visas

I have an italian student visa but i have changed my mind not to go for masters due to some personal reasons. Will the unused visa be a problem for me applying for other schengen countries in future?

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, an unused visa is no problem.  You should not be surprised, however, if questions about it come up.  As long as you have a reasonable explanation, which you seem to have, the matter will likely end there.

I know someone who was about to immigrate to Canada when she found a job in another country.  She no longer needs a visa to visit Canada, but when she did, her visa interviews always included a question about why she never immigrated.  The interviewer always accepted her explanation about finding the job.